# Move div to bottom of parent with other requirements

Tags: html, css, flexbox, position

How can I allign the child div to the bottom of the parent div? The solution needs to keep the hr width full, keep the padding of the parent div working and keep the text aligned to the right.

Why previous answer aren't working:

- position: relative on parent and position: absolute with bottom: 0px on child doesn't work because it shrinks the hr and it ignores the padding from the parent div.
- Flexbox doesn't work because my parent is already being used as a flexbox with different properties and it also shrinks the hr.

I will of course look at answers containing positioning or flexbox but I have tried what I know of it without getting to a good solution.

```css
.parent {
  width: 500px;
  height: 250px;
  background-color: gray;
  padding: 10px;
}

.child {
  height: 50px;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    <hr>
    <label>I am Batman</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give `margin-top: auto` and `width: 100%` to the *child* element:

```css
.parent {
  width: 500px;
  height: 250px;
  background-color: gray;
  padding: 10px;
  display: flex;
}

.child {
  height: 50px;
  text-align: right;
  margin-top: auto;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    <hr>
    <label>I am Batman</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with the `align-self: flex-end`:

```css
.parent {
  width: 500px;
  height: 250px;
  background-color: gray;
  padding: 10px;
  display: flex;
}

.child {
  flex: 1; /* mimics "width: 100%" */
  align-self: flex-end; /* affects horizontal alignment, places itself at the bottom of the parent element */
  height: 50px;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    <hr>
    <label>I am Batman</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add position: relative to the parent and add a few things to the child. This solution works if you are not able to use flexbox on the parent container (though flexbox is a better and easier fix)

Notes:

- Margin on the child replaces the padding you loose when using position: absolute
- To fill the width use calc(100% - (10px*2)). This makes the div 100%, then subtracts a 10px margin on each side. This results in a div that fills the area correctly.

```css
.parent {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: gray;
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
}

.child {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: orange;
  text-align: right;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  margin: 10px;
  width: calc(100% - (10px*2));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since I have used position relative and absolute in parent-child div, it ignores the padding. So you have to set bottom in child div to display it as you want.

```css
.parent {
  width: 500px;
  height: 250px;
  background-color: gray;
  padding: 10px;
  position:relative;
}

.child {
  width:calc(100% - (10px*2));
  height: 50px;
  text-align: right;
  position:absolute;
  bottom:10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    <hr>
    <label>I am Batman</label>
  </div>
</div>
```